# Opening Facebook Page Results in Force Close

Tags: ios, facebook, unity-game-engine

I'm making a mobile game using **Unity3D 5.1.4**, and inside my game I'd like the players to be able to open up my Facebook fanpage.

I have implemented it using this code:

```
Application.OpenURL("fb://page/442219965978230");
```

On Android it works fine, however the problem is on iOS.
I tested it on my **iPad Air 2, iOS 9.2**.
The Facebook app opened for a short moment, but then closed by itself.
This happens **ONLY** when the user is already logged into his Facebook account.
There was no error log when I checked in XCode...

After trying other games, I found out that opening Facebook would show a permission dialog "*[Appname] wants to open Facebook*", while in my game that dialog was never shown.

Is this what's causing the force close? Or something else?
I suspect it has something to do with iOS 9, isn't it?
If so, what do I need to do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change **page** to **profile**. For some reason, this is the fix for this problem.

```
Application.OpenURL("fb://profile/442219965978230");
```

Comment: Oh my God... Such a simple fix. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yeah that facebook problem is only on iOS. Android has its facebook problem too but a different one.